# equivalent to list() of php in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list

there some method equal list() of php in C#?

usage [list()](http://php.net/list) in PHP:

```
$array = array('foo','baa'); 
list($foo, $baa)  = $array; 

echo $foo; //foo
echo $baa; //baa
```

equivalent in javascript:

```
var arr = ['foo','baa']; 
var foo;
var baa; 
[foo, baa] = arr;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no equivalent in safe c#. if you want an unsafe example, let me know and I'll post it (its quite complex).

Comment: @Dani: Am I crazy for **hoping** for an unsafe solution? :/

Comment: Your javascript does not work in a browser. Have you tested your code?

Comment: @wared: My javascript?

Comment: Yes, your Javascript code sample.

Comment: @wared: Strage. It still works for me. What browser and version have you tried?  I'm on firefox browser 3.6+.

Comment: Last Chrome version. I have copied the code in the console and it throws this error : "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

Comment: @wared: Try on firefox.

Comment: Ok on firefox, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct language equivalent in C#.  While [collection initializers](http://Unfortunately) can be used to construct the array, there is no way to extract elements directly.

This requires explicitly setting variables, ie:

```
var theArray = GetArrayFromSomewhere();
var foo = theArray[0]; 
var bar = theArray[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more similar to the original intention, though some might not like all the ceremony :

```
string a = null, b = null, c = null;

new ValList(v => a = v,
            v => b = v,
            v => c = v).SetFrom(new string[] { "foo", "bar" });

//here a is "foo", b will be "bar", and c is still null
```

And the simple helper class:

```
class ValList
{
    private Action<string>[] _setters;

    public ValList(params Action<string>[] refs)
    {
        _setters = refs;
    }

    internal void SetFrom(string[] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length && i < _setters.Length; i++)
            _setters[i](values[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do the original php (I know nothing about PHP) task in C# would be

```
        List<string> name_list = new List<string>{"transmogrify","untransmogrify"};
        name_list.ForEach(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

Which leads to the more general observation, that C# allows you to do a lot while leaving the variables in the array or list. LINQ in particular makes doing many things quite simple. So if you are looking for a way to replicate some PHP code in C# I would think in those terms. Just one parting example, if you had an array of ints you wanted to sum you could do this

```
       int[] some_ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
       int sum += some_ints.Sum();
```

Comment: This is where I point out that knowledge of PHP is essential to answering the question. `list` is a language construct that maps an array of values to a series of variables. Your C# equivalent simply foreaches a list of strings.

Comment: My point was twofold: first that the original code just did an echo  of the results so I was showing how to do the same thing. This led to point 2 which was that while PHP may have good reasons for moving an array to a series of variables, when moving to a new tool it sometimes pays to think in terms of the new toolset instead of trying to force things to work the way they did in the old tool (I even qualified my response since the motives behind the question were unknown). Finally the OP could have included your terse clarification to garner more responses from the PHP ignoramuses like me.

Answer (score 0):

As **Reed** said , 
There is no direct language equivalent in C#.

But you can create it like below ↓

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] tmp = new string[] { "foo", "baa" };

        string foo, baa;
        tmp.Go(out foo, out baa);

        Console.WriteLine(foo);
        Console.WriteLine(baa);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class PHPList
{
    public static void Go(this string[] soruce, out string p1, out string p2)
    {
        p1 = soruce[0] + "";
        p2 = soruce[1] + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that you have to overload the extension method for arbitrary types, argument counts, etc... you can't have `out params` parameters C#.

Comment: Would be nice though, `IEnumerable` extension method of `List(this IEnumerable<T> source, out params T[])`

Answer (score 0):

Just piggy-backing @Yoni's answer into an extension method. This was a cute and silly exercise; however, as has been pointed out in comments and answers, some language features simply *do not* port from one language to another.

In PHP, `list($a, $b) = $c` constitutes an assignment, and since no variable declarations are required (*the `list()` **is** the declaration*) it can provide terse and clean assignment syntax.

In C# however, since variable declarations are required prior to usage, you're better off simply assigning the value off the list at that time, as the following example will show.

Speaking of, incoming example:

```
public static void Into<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    params Action<TSource>[] actions) 
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(source, null)) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(actions, null)) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("actions");
    }
    foreach (var assignment in actions.Zip(source, (action, item) => new {
        Action = action,
        Item = item,
    })) {
        assignment.Action.Invoke(assignment.Item);
    }
}
```

So you can simply `collection.Into(o => a = o, o => ...);` for example:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
int e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

numbers.Into(o => a = o,
             o => b = o,
             o => c = o,
             o => d = o);

numbers.Into(o => e = o,
             o => f = o,
             o => g = o,
             o => h = o,
             o => i = o,
             o => j = o);
```

This will yield:

```
Console.WriteLine(a); // 1
Console.WriteLine(b); // 2
Console.WriteLine(c); // 3
Console.WriteLine(d); // 4
Console.WriteLine(e); // 1
Console.WriteLine(f); // 2
Console.WriteLine(g); // 3
Console.WriteLine(h); // 4
Console.WriteLine(i); // 5
Console.WriteLine(j); // 0
```

Perhaps some `Expression<>` magic can shorten it to:

```
numbers.Into(o => a,
             o => b,
             ... )
```